# Event Emitter emit at every request based on boolean

Tags: angular, rxjs

I often find myself within Angular applications Checking a boolean value to see if data is present, and if not I subscribe to an event emitter until the data is there.

```js
if(this.service.propertySet){
   this.property = service.property
}

else{
  this.service.propertyEmitter.subscribe((value)=>{
    this.property = value;
  })
}
```

How can I simplify this so I don't have to use an if statement in the case that there may or may not yet be data from a service?

Comment: Most commonly I do this based on the dependency of a global value being set that is reset when a user refreshes on the single page application.  If they browse to the view the value is already there, if not the value has to come from the server first.

Comment: More context might help, but it seems like you're misusing streams. If you just `.subscribe` to it, without using `.first`, you will get each value that's pushed through it, at which point you know there's a value. If you have a default value, look into `BehaviorSubject`, otherwise consider a `ReplaySubject` so subscribers get the latest value even if they subscribe after it was emitted.

Comment: If it's a SPA and they've browsed to the page then the stream never fires because I only emit when I get the initial value.

Comment: That's OK, it will emit *when you push that value through it*. I wrote a blog article on how you can use observables in services, maybe it's of some use to you: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html. But this needs a [mcve] to explain how you're handling values - it seems like you're treating a stream as a single value, which isn't going to help.

Comment: I think after looking further your the correct answer could be that I'm using streams incorrectly :).  In that case each time I've used this pattern is a different case so I can't really put a Verifiable question.  Generally what I was looking for was BehaviorSubject's functionality.

Comment: I still have not found one BehaviorSubject example that could not be more clearly/easily re-written without them. Still looking for a canonical example.